Is it dangerous to leave “.DS_Store” files left in Git commit history?
I forgot to add it to my .gitignore and although I've added .DS_Store to my .gitignore now, I was wondering if it was dangerous to leave for anyone to see in my Git commit history?
I'm not asking if .DS_Store files should be in my repo or not, but I'm asking if I should remove them from my previous commits, because if you go to my commit history, you can access this file. It's already been removed from my current commit.

What do you mean by "dangerous"?

While not the question asked, gitignore.io includes .DS_Store in their macOS template, so I believe there's a compelling reason why it should not be included in the first place. (no affiliation, just a happy user of it)

Previous question on Stack Overflow: is it dangerous to leave DS_store files left in git commit history?

Have a look at what is stored in the .DS_Store file. Whether it is going to be dangerous or not depends on whether there is anything that could be stored in that file in your particular directory that is dangerous. The answer, I suspect, is "no" since you've presumably only had the project files and any other intermediary and project files you've excluded from git in that directory anyway and there's no way for anyone to use this information to harm you or your project.
However, since it depends on information that only you have access to - i.e. what exactly you've put in that directory that isn't in Git - we can't answer that question for you. If you're really worried, then you can delete them but it is unlikely to be necessary for your protection.

My work is just personal and there's no subfolders or files in the folder that I'd be worried about, I thought DS_store could store some more info about my paths and computer info but I guess not so it should be ok to leave then

I would remove them git rm .DS_Store and update your ignore file.
They don’t add to your project and could leak data from other file names you didn’t stage for checkin. You should know best on what file names and metadata could leak based on what you stored in those directories and how many people might fork your project or looked closely for clues what files you checked in.

Just to be clear: by "remove" here, do you mean rewriting the past commit history to erase any trace of the .DS_Store files? I'm guessing so based on context, but given that "remove" in git usually means creating a new commit that deletes the files, I was wondering if it might be worth saying so explicitly.

Completely a preference; but if you don't care about the file being in the commit history you could opt for simply making another commit using git rm .DS_Store rather than trying to force pushing historical commits to completely expunge it.  I interpreted "remove" as being equivalent to rm.

For sure do the git rm - the rest is highly subjective. How professional is your work, how many eyes see the repo, do you mix personal files with work files, do you get paid and have several clients files in the same folder. We can’t know your threat model for privacy and everyone will have their tolerance for leaking data and it won’t match everyone else, @DavidZ

My work is just personal and there's no subfolders or files in the folder that I'd be worried about, I thought DS_store could store some more info about my paths and computer info but I guess not so it should be ok to leave then

If anyone is curious, there are several projects that reverse engineer the .DS_Store binary file format. Here is one https://github.com/dimme/DSStoreDump wrapper around one library https://pypi.org/project/ds-store/

I'd go one step further. Don't put .DS_Store in your project's .gitignore. Ignore it globally: set up a global gitignore file like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335487/2072269 and ignore it there.

@muru I'd do both, tbh. You want to ensure that it's also ignored for other contributors too.

@muru feel free to edit my answer - much better than my focus on this one repo I think.

@bmike I followed your suggestion and suggested an edit, alas it was rejected: https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/347824

From an aesthetics standpoint, leaving a bunch of .DS_Store files all over your repo is just not clean, or dare I say, elegant?
I like what bmike said, regardless of the data leaking, which is the primary reason to clean up this situation, it's also a good discipline to ensure that only the files that are absolutely necessary are in a git repo, particularly a public one.
I didn't notice this until I saw someone else's repo that had many many directories and every one had the .DS_Store in it, and then I found about possibly leaking data, so like muru said, do it globally.
